# How to wrap an entire layout?

Tags: html, css, layout

Usually the `background_wrapper` does it, but the left column isn't aligned. Only when its without absolute positioning.

Isn't there a way that no matter what the containing element is, the content will be aligned within a certain width? To organize everything.

I take out positiong: absolute, and it aligns it. But what if I apply absolute positioning later on?

What is a good way to wrap a site into 1024px?

```css
#wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 25px;
  width: 960px;
}

body {
  background: repeating-linear-gradient( 45deg, transparent, transparent 10px, #ccc 10px, #ccc 20px), /* on "bottom" */
  linear-gradient( to bottom, #fff, #999);
}

#header {
  background-color: blue;
  left: 55px;
  top: 15px;
  width: 910px;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 4;
}

#nav_left {
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  left: 60px;
  top: 140px;
  width: 140px;
  height: 280px;
  z-index: 12;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<HTML>

<head>

  <title>UNAWAKENED.NET - Welcome!</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">

  <body>

    <section id="wrapper">

      <div id="header">Header</div>

      <section id="nav_left"></section>

    </section>
  </body>
```

Comment: So you want 1024x768?

Comment: Aligned to what? If you remove `position:absolute` it changes position, sure, because `left` and `top` no longer work. But what is your goal? And why do you need position:absolute for that matter?

Comment: You specify `left: 60px` in your CSS. How could this section be aligned on the left ? It can't, you specified otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

If i understood your question correctly, the main problem is that `absolute` element is 60px left from body left side, not from wrapper left side. You should use `position:relative;` for parent items if you want to position children `absolute` elements from their boundaries.

Conslusion: use `position:relative;` for your `#wrapper`

```css
#wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 25px;
  width: 960px;
  position: relative;
}

body {
  background: repeating-linear-gradient( 45deg, transparent, transparent 10px, #ccc 10px, #ccc 20px), /* on "bottom" */
  linear-gradient( to bottom, #fff, #999);
}

#header {
  background-color: blue;
  left: 55px;
  top: 15px;
  width: 910px;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 4;
}

#nav_left {
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  left: 60px;
  top: 140px;
  width: 140px;
  height: 280px;
  z-index: 12;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<HTML>

<head>

  <title>UNAWAKENED.NET - Welcome!</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">

  <body>

    <section id="wrapper">

      <div id="header">Header</div>

      <section id="nav_left"></section>

    </section>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I may take a wild guess, you want the `nav_left` to be located just below the header, while still being positioned absolutely.

In that case, the solution is to give the wrapper `position:relative` so that the `nav_left` is in the same container as the header. And then the `nav_left` needs `top:50px; left:0` to end up just below the header (because the header is 50 pixels high).

```css
#wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 25px;
  width: 960px;
  position: relative;
}

body {
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent, transparent 10px, #ccc 10px, #ccc 20px), /* on "bottom" */
  linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff, #999);
}

#header {
  background-color: blue;
  left: 55px;
  top: 15px;
  width: 910px;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 4;
}

#nav_left {
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 50px;
  width: 140px;
  height: 280px;
  z-index: 12;
}
```

```html
<section id="wrapper">

  <div id="header">Header</div>

  <section id="nav_left"></section>

</section>
```

Note: you have also have `left` and `top` in the css for the header, but those do nothing, since the header isn't positioned.

Comment: oic about left XD - Its copied from Photoshop. Im trying to incorporate a more static design to the original counterpart its being moched up in Phothoshop as.

I asked earlier about the HTML part, but looks like that was answered.

Thanks alot gents.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position), absolutely positioned elements:

> Do not leave space for the element. Instead, position it at a specified position relative to its ***closest positioned ancestor*** or to the containing block. Absolutely positioned boxes can have margins, they do not collapse with any other margins.

This means that if you want your `position: absolute`'d element to be affected at all by your `#wrapper`, you need to give `#wrapper` a `position` property. Otherwise, it will default to the containing block, which in this case is the browser window.

As of right now, you have `top` and `left` attributes applied, but those are relative to the top left corner of the browser window. You're going to want your `#nav_left` to position itself relative to the wrapper, which means `#wrapper` needs a position attribute. Try this:

```
#wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 25px;
  width: 960px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the content is 1024px wide, the `wrapper` element can have this width set. The menu can float on the left. The `wrapper` element has css `display` property set to `inline-block` to allow centering.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <title>UNAWAKENED.NET - Welcome!</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">

  <style>
    body {
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    #wrapper {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 1024px !important;
      text-align: left;
    }
    
    #nav_left {
      float: left;
      width: 200px;
      background-color: red;
    }
    
    #header {
      background-color: blue;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <section id="wrapper">

    <div id="header">Header</div>

    <section id="nav_left">
      left
    </section>

    content here

  </section>

</body>

</html>
```